# Why is package name doubled in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, apk

When creating a new Xamarin.Android project and giving it the name *OurProduct.Mobile* the package name will be *OurProduct.Mobile.OurProduct.Mobile*. The apk name will then also be OurProduct.Mobile.OurProduct.Mobile.apk.

Will I run into trouble somewhere if I change the package name to just *OurProduct.Mobile*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the package name is mandatory, When you create a new Xamarin Android application, what Visual studio does is creates a by default package name the procedure for which is it takes the Assembly Name and Default Namespace from your project file merges them both and adds a period in between, So if your default namespace is `ABCD` and your assembly name is `EFGH` you end up with a package name like `ABCD.EFGH`

Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

Companies use their reversed Internet domain name to begin their package names—for example, com.example.mypackage for a package named mypackage created by a programmer at example.com.

Things that get affected if you change your package name :

- Package Name in android is basically a bundle identifier, so if you change the package name android will consider your application as a different application 
  if you try to install it on the same device you can see that even google play considers it as a different application.
- Secondly, if you have a google service like maps or firebase cloud messaging that need your package name while configuring them on change of package name these services will stop behaving properly

**Update:**

In the latest version of Xamarin.Android the change has been made for the package name where it already comes something like this :

```
com.companyname.projectname
```

Where companyname is your company name and projectname is the desired name you want for your project.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is package name doubled in Xamarin.Android?

It is the default way to name your package. The naming rules for the package name are a bit more restrictive, one of them is that it must have at least two segments (one or more dots). So it will double your project name to fulfill that requirement and in case of duplicate.

You could change the package name by going to AndroidManifest.xml and change the package name attribute. In VS, you could right-click the project name -> Properties -> Android Manifest -> Package Name. It better to change the name to java version, such as com.AuthorName.ProjectName.

> Will I run into trouble somewhere if I change the package name to just OurProduct.Mobile?

Package name is used to identify your app. For example, if you change the package name, your phone and Google Play Store will recognize it as a different app.
 
If the app is not published, it will not make you run into trouble.